# How do I make my post form handling more flexible

Tags: python, django

I have written what I hope to be a re-usable Django app, but I have a bit of a conundrum on how to make the post form handling flexible. The simplified version of my view code looks like:

```
def do_form(request, entity_id, template_name, success_url):

    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_valid():

            #do some business logic

            return HttpResponseRedirect(finished_url)
    return render_to_response(template_name, 
                              {'form': form},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have followed the advice in James Bennets book  "Practical Django Projects" and so you can now configure the template and the success url in the url conf, so for example my url conf could look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',


          url(r'^do/(?P<entity_id>\d+)/$', 
          view = 'do_form',
          name = 'do_form_view',
          kwargs={'template_name':'form.html',
                    'success_url':'/finish/'},),

          url(r'^finish/$', 
          view = 'finish',
          name = 'finish_view')
)
```

This is all very well and good but when I have come to use this in my real world application I find myself in a situation that this form sits in the middle of some workflow, and I want the success url to be something like `/continue/<workflow_id>/` , and the problem is that you can only have a hardcoded url in the url conf, and the workflow_id will vary every time I hit the do_form code.

Can any one suggest a way to get around this?

Comment: Well a quick way to achieve what you're asking is to simply have 2 urls point to the same view.

You can have `url(r'^success/$', view = 'finish')`
and `url(r'^failure/$', view = 'finish',)` and render you're response to each of these based on the 'success' or 'failure' of your `do_form` view.

Comment: sorry the formatting of my question stripped out a key part that made it difficult to see what i was getting at, I have edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by changing the following..

in `do_form()` in **views.py**
change the `return HttpResponseRedirect` to

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/continue/%s' %(workflowid))
```

And in **urls.py**, you can have

```
url(r'^continue/(?P<workflowid>\d+)/$', 
          view = 'continue',
          name = 'continue_view')
```

and for the `continue()` view in **views.py**

```
def continue(request, workflowid=None):
 ...
```

This way.. whenever you access the url `/continue/` without a number, workflowid will be equal to `None`. Every other time when you do have a workflowid attached for e.g. like `/continue/23/` , then inside your `continue()` view you can access that id through the variable `workflowid`.

Comment: yeah I thought of that but if I want to reuse this app in other situations having the workflow argument in the view doesn't allow me much flexibility...

Comment: As long as you are always assigning it a value (None in this case) by doing `workflowid=None`, you do not have to worry about not supplying a workflowid in some cases.
What is the hindrance to flexibility that you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a hypothethical "flexible" success_url to a view, that view MUST supply the desired identifier. So if you mismatch the URL and the view, we can't avoid having a "breach of contract" between the two.

Therefore if we are to have flexible URLs, some kind of contract shall have to be enforced, and there will be no loss of generality if we do this through a special syntax for URLs:

```
  'finished_url':  '/finish/<workflow_id>/'
```

Then, of course, the view shall have to instantiate the variable through a string replacement to honor its side of the contract: instead of

```
  return HttpResponseRedirect(finished_url)
```

you will have

```
  return HttpResponseRedirect(finished_url.replace('<workflow_id>', WorkflowID))
```

This should keep things reasonably simple.

When reusing code, you will have to keep in mind that `<workflow_id>` is *whatever that app uses to call workflow id*, and that's why I use a complicated string such as `workflow_id` instead of `id` or maybe `$1`.

**EDIT**: I was going to add the code for the next step (intercepting workflow ID in argument of finish), but I see that keithxm23 beat me to the punch :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way people have been "overriding" Django's function-based generic views for years: simply wrap the view in another view:

```
def custom_do_form(request, entity_id, template_name, success_url):
    template_name = some_method_to_get_template()
    return do_form(request, entity_id, template_name, success_url)
```

Comment: i am not sure that answers my question @keithxm23 was close but it doesn't give me the flexibility I need